# Views Grouping field:Add Ordered class to Grouping row

Tags: views, theming

I use Views and Grouping field to integrate my data.
But i need each grouping row ordered.

I want to override the views-view-grouping.tpl.php, and change the "view-grouping" class to "view-grouping-1","view-grouping-2","view-grouping-3"...

The original code is belowed:

```
    <?php

/**
 * @file
 * This template is used to print a single grouping in a view.
 *
 * It is not actually used in default Views, as this is registered as a theme
 * function which has better performance. For single overrides, the template is
 * perfectly okay.
 *
 * Variables available:
 * - $view: The view object
 * - $grouping: The grouping instruction.
 * - $grouping_level: Integer indicating the hierarchical level of the grouping.
 * - $rows: The rows contained in this grouping.
 * - $title: The title of this grouping.
 * - $content: The processed content output that will normally be used.
 */

?>
<div class="view-grouping">
  <div class="view-grouping-header"><?php print $title; ?></div>
  <div class="view-grouping-content">
    <?php print $content; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The File is located at all/module/views/theme/

Does someone meet the same problem before?

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript?

```
$('.view-grouping').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('view-grouping-' + (i+1));
});
```